# Mutation in Genetic Algorithm: error at reversing bits

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, mutation

I'm building mutation process in genetic algorithm for feature selection.
Here is the code:

```
def mutation(pm):
    sum_mut = int(round(pm*total))
    i = 0
    while i < sum_mut:
        mut_row = int(random.random()*total)
        mut_col = int(random.random()*2393)
        offspring[mut_col][mut_row] ^= 1  
        i = i + 1
mutation(0.05)
print offspring
```

The mutation process is reversing the bit. Bit 1 means selected feature, and bit 0 means unselected feature.

`pm` is the mutation probability, `sum_mut` is the sum of mutation, `total` is sum of all individuals plus offsprings from crossover process. Number `2393` is the sum of features. `offspring` is a dataframe, consist of all individuals plus offsprings from crossover process.

That code doesn't work. Here is the traceback of error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-6f4580f1221c> in <module>()
      8         mut_col = int(random.random()*2393)
      9         offspring[mut_col][mut_row] ^= 1
---> 10 mutation(0.05)
     11 offspring

<ipython-input-38-6f4580f1221c> in mutation(pm)
      7         mut_row = int(random.random()*total)
      8         mut_col = int(random.random()*2393)
----> 9         offspring[mut_col][mut_row] ^= 1
     10 mutation(0.05)
     11 offspring

C:\Users\HEWLETT PACKARD\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   1962             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   1963         else:
-> 1964             return self._getitem_column(key)
   1965 
   1966     def _getitem_column(self, key):

C:\Users\HEWLETT PACKARD\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _getitem_column(self, key)
   1969         # get column
   1970         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 1971             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   1972 
   1973         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

C:\Users\HEWLETT PACKARD\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1643         res = cache.get(item)
   1644         if res is None:
-> 1645             values = self._data.get(item)
   1646             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1647             cache[item] = res

C:\Users\HEWLETT PACKARD\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3588 
   3589             if not isnull(item):
-> 3590                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3591             else:
   3592                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

C:\Users\HEWLETT PACKARD\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.pyc in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2442                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2443             except KeyError:
-> 2444                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2445 
   2446         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 2392L
```

Can you help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the error traceback

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I added the traceback

Comment: `KeyError` when accessing `offspring[mut_col][mut_row]`... the keys you calculate with 'int(random.random()*total)` and `mut_col = int(random.random()*2393)` are incorrect.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Any suggestion to generate random column and row?

Comment: yes, maybe it is better to use `random.randint()` or `random.randrange()` look them up to verify the inclusion/exclusion of the top of range.
However, maybe your error is born from incorrect data in the `offspring ` nested structure? I have no way to tell with the info provided.